# Can you disable gpu rasterization in Google Chrome on a specific SVG element?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have an SVG graphic being displayed on a web page and I have noticed that on some computers the complex linearGradient filling a Rect is not showing all of the Stops correctly whereas on other computers it displays fine.

If I head to chrome://flags and set the "GPU rasterization" to "Disabled" then the gradient renders correctly on all computers (that I've tested).

Is there a way via HTML/CSS/Javascript to force Chrome to display the SVG without GPU rasterization so it will display correctly for all of my users?

[Image of incorrectly displayed gradient with GPU rasterization enabled (or defaulting to enabled) in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlOxj.png)

[Image of correct gradient with GPU rasterization disabled in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkBhN.png)

Example gradient in Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dynoben/6v7fLq5a/8/

```
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient"></linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="500" height="200" style="fill:url('#gradient')"></rect>
</svg>
<script>
d3.select('#gradient').selectAll('stop').remove();
var stopCount = 200;
d3.select('#gradient').selectAll('stop')
 .data(d3.range(0,stopCount,1)).enter()
 .append('stop').each(function(d,i){
   var item = d3.select(this);
   item.attr('stop-color', i%2==0 ? '#000000' : '#ffffff');
   item.attr('offset', 100*i/stopCount+'%');
});
</script>
```

Note, this only seems to be an issue using Chrome.

**Update:**
This is a known issue with Chrome (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=892711&desc=5).  I've worked around it by replacing the linearGradient with a pattern (using rects to replicate the gradient stops) which is applied as the Fill for the path object as before.

Answer (score 0):

If you FORCE hardware acceleration does it solve the problem?

I have a feeling you're actually seeing an issue with the CPU rasterizing stuff to improve performance when it should be allowing the GPU to do it. After reading some of the GPU Rasterization issues, it sounds like that doesn't work correctly if hardware acceleration isn't being applied.

You can force an element to get hardware acceleration with CSS

```
.element {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

I'm a bit confused about the need to turn it off since `gpu-rasterization` on desktop is still marked as a [flagged feature](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromium-graphics/how-to-get-gpu-rasterization) you have to enable. If your issues are on mobile, you need to mess with the `<meta name="viewport">` tag in the HTML file. Here's the [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromium-graphics/how-to-get-gpu-rasterization).

If you can replicate the issue consistently, you may have found a bug that should be [reported to the Chromium team](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines).

Comment: Unfortunately adding that CSS doesn't change anything. I've only seen the issue on Macbooks, not on mobile browsers. My new MacBook PRO and the Macbooks of some of my clients (not sure what version).  It happens 100% of the time unless I turn of Chrome's GPU rasterization on my Macbook PRO, and 100% of the time when I force GPU rasterisation to be used on my iMac. I'll dig out a PC and try it on that as well before raising an bu with the Chromium team.

Comment: I raised a bug with the Chromium team and the poor performance of GPU rasterization of linear gradients is a "known limitation" when there are more than a handful of gradient stops. This is the Chromium issue that is related to the problem - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=892711&desc=5  I've ended up using a Pattern in the SVG Def made up of Rects replacing the gradient stops. The pattern gets applied as a fill to my path in the same way as the linearGradient and it now works across all browsers. A bit slower to draw in Chrome though unfortunately.